# Unable to get to step 2 of checkout cart in Magneto 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, frontend

I am having a problem with the checkout cart where I cannot get to the second step of the checkout process.  When I click on the "Review and Payments" button nothing happens as shown in the pictures below.

Page 1[image: Checkout Issue]
Page 2  [image: Checkout Issue 2]
I also do not see a next button at the bottom of the page.  I know it worked at one point in the past because I was able to place a test order which I can still view on the backend.  Since then, I have installed a new theme and an unrelated extension used to create a grid/list of subcategories on category pages.  As of right now there are no error messages in the debug.log or the exception.log files.  I also tried switching to the Luma theme and the issue was still happening there.  I was wondering if anyone has an idea for what may be causing this.

Comment: Check if there is an error message in the browser console or in the DevTools networking tab if there are any failed requests.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by disabling and then reenabling the modules Magento_amqp and Magento_WebApiAsync.